# NGinx - rewrite, proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Добрый день,

Имеется сайт mydomen.ru/
Требуется редирект на локальный ип 192.168.1.10:8080/asd/asd.xhtml

пробую следующим образом:

```
location / {
rewrite ^(.+)$ /asd/asd.xhtml$1 last;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:8080/;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

Выводится ошибка циклического перенаправления.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял замысел автора вопроса то как-то так:

```
location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.10:8080/asd/asd.xhtml;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```